# Calculate size of array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I want to create an array of size n, where n is defined by the variables of a loop, but I don't know how to pre-calculate the size of the array.
We can assume that start < end and step > 0.

```
int start; // Initialized by user
int end; // Initialized by user
int step; // Initialized by user

int size = ? // What is the formula for the size ?

Object[] array = new Object[size];
int index=0;

for(int i=start; i<=end; i+=step){
    array[index++]=new Object();
}
```

I could just use a List and then copy the elements to an array, but that seems like a detour.

It's *not*: (end - start) / size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int size = ceiling(float(end - start + 1)/size);
```

You need to add `1` because you use `i <= end`, so it has to include the end value.

Comment: start=3, end=7, step=2. Iterates 3 times, but (7-3+1)/2=2. I don't think adding the ceiling function would solve the problem, would it ?